# What are the options needed to extract Filepaths from a H5 file using h5dump

Tags: powershell

I'm using Powershell for scripting at work.
A problem we have is that we need to copy a subset of the results associated with a given h5 file.

How do you extract the filePaths for a given SparseObjectLabel when using h5dump?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague so answer will be minimal.

You have to use [PSH5X - A WINDOWS POWERSHELL MODULE FOR HDF5](https://www.hdfgroup.org/projects/PSH5X/) or at least regex matching to get what you want.

Comment: The link here is malformed.